# can Microsoft Outlook's Auto-response text be programmed?

Tags: vba, outlook

Just wondering if there's a macro or other method to do a task such as inserting the Sender's name into the autoresponse "out of office" message.  I have seen some of the other VBA macros that do things like building defined text strings, but not this.
In pseudo-code, assuming that Outlook is set up to send Out of Office messages, something to fill the return message with 
`Dear $Sender_Name$ , I will return on Feb 30th,...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that. OOF template is static.